# Group By Linked IDs

Tags: group-by, hive, aggregation, self-join

I have some items in hive table. Id of the items are frequently changed. I have one table to manage these changes. Columns of the table is like below:

```
Old_Item_ID, 
New_Item_ID,
Change_Timestamp
```

How can I find the Oldest Item Id, Latest Item Id and Latest Change Timestamp of each individual item from this hive table.

**Sample I/P data:**

```
X01, X25, 2014/01/01 00:00
X02, X42, 2000/05/25 00:00
X69, X92, 2015/01/23 00:00
X25, X69, 2014/06/20 00:00
```

**Sample O/P:**

```
X01, X92, 2015/01/23 00:00
X02, X42, 2000/05/25 00:00
```

**Note:** Recursive CTE is not supported in HIVE.